# Storing and Updating an array in a smart contract (for creating permissioned networks and updating members)

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

Can I define a smart contract including a dynamic array that I can update its content later?

precisely,I have some IoT(Internet of things) nodes sharing the received data from sensors with each others. I partitioned them to 2 permissioned networks: Network 1 includes: X,Y,Z nodes trusting each other. Network 2 includes: M,N,O nodes trusting each other.

Can I define a smart contract to each network containing the list of nodes (their PK) in order to create **permissioned networks** that enables nodes to accept the data of only its own peers in own network?

For instance, smart contract 1 includes the PK of X,Y,Z and enable them share data with each other. smart contract 2 includes the PK of M,N,O.

Due to some conditions, for changing these partitions, for example, moving node Z from network 1 to network 2.

Can I update arrays including the list of members in smart contracts 1 and 2.

That is, the list of new smart contract 1 is updated to X,Y,

and new smart contract 2 is M,N,O and plus new node Z can share data with network 2 members. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your particular case it is better to take advantage of nested mappings. 
You mentioned sensors, so I’m assuming you will not be iterating through ever-evolving dynamic arrays (this could have serious consequences in regards to security, e.g. exploiting cost > block gas limit).

To get your started you could do something as shown below (I’m sure you can take it from there, in regards to following proper C-E-I design pattern etc).

```
 contract PermissionedNetworks {
        //Track nodes and their particular network state (their network permission).  
        mapping(uint8 => mapping(bytes32 => bool)) public networkNodes;

        //Add a node to a particular network partition/zone.
        function addNodeToPermissionedNetwork(bytes32 _nodeID, uint8 _networkID, bool _nodeState) public {
            networkNodes[_networkID][_nodeID] = networkNodes[_networkID][_nodeID] = _nodeState;
        }
    }
```